# is there a simple way to yield all elements in an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

The following code when compiled is lowered into over 100 lines of code in a state machine, just to enumerate the inner IEnumerable, which would have its own state machine.

This feels inefficient.

```
public abstract class C {
    public abstract (IEnumerable<int>,bool) getABatch();
    IEnumerable<int> getLots(){
        bool hasMore;
        do{
             (var stuff,hasMore)=getABatch();
             foreach(var thing in stuff)
                 yield return thing;
        } while (hasMore)
    }
}
```

([Sharplab version](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMAsDcBYAUCkBmCBDARgZwBcAnLAYwKgCYIBhCAbxQmak10JPKmnQB4AVAHwQA5gFMCAQQBCWAqQAWAwQAoAlEmQtufIaIkAZAPYE8y9Yy3btANyxEIhAK4AzFwF5xU2fKVD1mtbaLkZEYmQKKnYOBAoAlgB2IhCJjgSuLmpMQUEw0FAA7BCxiSKBLAC+KBVAA==))

I want to get lots of batches and return them all as 1 long enumerable. I'd prefer to not build i long list, as i don't know how much data will come through (could be millions of items).

Question:
Is there a better way to handle this enumerable than manually yielding them all the inner elements?
It feels like there should be an easier way to do this, given the inner enumerable has all the info it needs.

Comment: No, there is not. Even if there were syntax for this, the method `getLots` would still need its own state machine, of course

Comment: `(the real code has this code in a loop, so just 'return getABatch()' isn't an option)` Could you show a meaningful [mcve], to make that clearer?

Comment: Can't we directly return getABatch() which is an IEnumerable

Comment: "This code is actually in a loop" - so start looking in the opposite direction - are their LINQ operators that allow you to describe the behaviour you need without having you have to write an actual explicit loop? E.g. `SelectMany` to flatten a list of lists, as an example.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason you need to specifically enumerate over the getABatch collection? If not, you could just `return getABatch();`. If yes, but nothing else needs to happen in the loop, you could also use the `ToArray()`extension, which will iterate over the collection for you and then you can return the array, which is still an IEnumerable.

EDIT: I see you've edited the question to fetch batches in a while loop. In this case I would say there's actually nothing wrong with using a yield return.
However, you could initialize a result collection and simply add everything to it before finishing.

```
IEnumerable<int> getLots(){
    bool hasMore;
    var result = new List<int>();
    do{
         (var stuff,hasMore)=getABatch();
         result.AddRange(stuff);
    } while (hasMore)
    return result;
}
```